# Simple jQuery example not working (hiding element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have here a simple jQuery example wherein an element should be hidden. But the following code does not work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').hide();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Hi</div>
I'm here
</body>
</html>
```

I added the ready function but it still doesn't work. What I'm missing?

Comment: you should use something like firebug to track errors...

Comment: you are missing the mirror image of this smiley ;( (at the end of the function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `);` at the end, it's that simple.

Should read:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a bracket and a semicolon at the end of your jquery code. See the code below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){         
            $('#test').hide();     
    });
```

Comment: Thanks m90 for the correction :-)

Comment: I don't think ampersand was what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').hide();
}
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').hide();
});
```

you are missing

```
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out a closing ")" at the end of the function.

Comment: Syntax errors like this is pretty easy to spot using a browser debugging tool - I use google chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a ); after your document ready call

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').hide();
    }); //<----------------------------Right here!
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">Hi</div>
I'm here
</body>
</html>
```

You have to close the ready. added an extra parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Missing **);**

Correct:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test').hide();
    });
```